# Change format of value in input from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `data` variable holding an object like this:

```js
{
  "details": {
    "id": 10,
    "name": John Doe,
    "hobbies": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Football"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Badminton"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Running"
      }
    ],
    "dob": 1989-12-31
  }
}
```

I retrieve it using this AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{{ route('askdata') }}",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 'id': $('#member_id').val(), },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#id').val(data.details.id);
    $('#name').val(data.details.name);
    $('#dob').val(data.details.dob);
    $('#hobbies').val(JSON.stringify(data.details.hobbies, ['name']));
  }
});
```

I get a value in the `hobbies` input like this:

```
[{"name":"Football"},{"name":"Badminton"},{"name":"Running"}]
```

How can I change this to get the values like `Football, Badminton, Running`?

Comment: You will have to parse the data to an object, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current logic is building a JSON string from the `hobbies` array. To get the output you want you can use `map()` to build an array of the hobby names which you can then `join()` together to form a single string:

```js
let data = {"details":{"id": 10,"name": 'John Doe',"hobbies": [{"id": 1,"name": "Football"},{"id": 2,"name": "Badminton"},{"id": 3,"name": "Running"}],"dob": '1989-12-31'}}

$('#hobbies').val(data.details.hobbies.map(o => o.name).join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hobbies" size="25" />
```

Also note that your `data` object is missing some quotes around the `name` and `dob` properties, but I assume that was just a typo in the question otherwise you'd get no output at all.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{{ route('askdata') }}",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 'id': $('#member_id').val(), },
  success: function(data) {
    const { details: {id, name, dob, hobbies} } = data
    $('#id').val(id);
    $('#name').val(name);
    $('#dob').val(dob);
    $('#hobbies').val(JSON.stringify(hobbies.map(hobby => {
      return {name: hobby.name}
    })));
  }
});
```